# How can I apply CICrystallize filter iOS 7?

Tags: ios, core-image

I'm working with Photo app using Xcode 5 and iOS7. The problem is that when I apply CICrystallize filter and run the project the screen of the simulator goes blank. Could anyone help me?
The implementation of the method is:

```
- (IBAction)cristalizar:(id)sender {
    CIImage *imagen = [[CIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:self.imagenView.image.CGImage];

    CIFilter *cristalizar = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CICrystallize"];
    [cristalizar setDefaults];
    CIVector *vector = [CIVector vectorWithX:150 Y:150];
    [cristalizar setValue:imagen forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [cristalizar setValue:@20.00f forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey];
    [cristalizar setValue:vector forKey:kCIInputCenterKey];

    CIImage *resultado = [cristalizar valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

    CIContext *contexto = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgImagen = [contexto createCGImage:resultado fromRect:[resultado extent]];
    self.imagenView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImagen];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`CICrystallize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CICrystallize) is not available on iOS.

> **Availability**
>
> Available in OS X v10.4 and later.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't focus in that condition

Comment: Available in iOS 9 and later.